# Сервис работает некорректно

Tags: java, android

Получаю время с помощью

```
Date today = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
String date = DATE_FORMAT.format(today);
```

и посылаю на сервер. Сервер же обрабатывает их.

Проблема в том, что сервис иногда перестает посылать данные. Сервис засыпает на 2 минуты и потом просыпается сам же.

Как быть? Я добавил в меню батарейки отключение оптимизации к моему приложению, но все равно сервис засыпает и сам же пробуждается. Да еще и на зарядке сервис не засыпает. То есть подключаю телефон к ноуту, хочу посмотреть через мониторинг в чем проблема (сервис-то работает как надо). Думаю это от того, что он подключен к ноуту и заряжается. Но понять проблему это мне не помогло (я ж добавил приложение в список отключенных от оптимизации).

Как понять такое поведение ?

Comment: А может вместо потока сознания вы внятно напишите проблему?

Comment: Получаю время телефона в приложение и посылаю данные в БД.все осуществляеется в сервисе.После того как телефон блокировн и экран выключен  сервис работает некорректно .Перестает посылать данные .с интервалом до 5 минут.Но как включаю экран он сразу же работает.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091270/how-can-i-keep-my-android-service-running-when-the-screen-is-turned-off

Comment: Спасибо флипии.благодарю за подсказку

Comment: @Flippy Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Comment: Снимаем минусы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091270/how-can-i-keep-my-android-service-running-when-the-screen-is-turned-off) решение на английском SO ->

Этот код поможет сервису работать, когда экран заблокирован.

```
PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

Для обновления

```
wakeLock.release();
```

`release` нужно вызывать, когда экран блокируется. `acquire` - когда разблокируется

Comment: спасибо все понел толькол кроме пункта обновления

Comment: @elik, дополнил ответ

Comment: спасибо это то  что мне нужно!

Comment: @elik, не за что :)